# Connecting three routers and one modem

Tags: router

I have one modem and three routers in my home office. I would like to have the first router to serve the office only, the second router would serve the house, and the third would be a VPN router. Routers 1 and 2 have printers connected to them.

The modem is connected  to a switch and the three routers are connected to the switch.

Setup

- Modem: 192.168.1.1
- DHCP: on

The three routers are configured as follows:

- Router 1: 192.168.2.1
- Router 2: 192.168.3.1
- Router 3: 192.168.4.1
- DHCP= on
- All routers have WiFi

When I enter the default gateway for any of router, it can't connect to the Internet. How can I get this working?

Comment: Since you're assigning some static IP's, try settings the DHCP pool start IP a little higher (for example, start at .10). That way there's actually space for your static IP clients.

Answer (score 0):

I should mention that I'm not a networking expert, but I've set up a few routers before. I think the problem you're having is that you have two layers of NAT happening which is breaking your routers from being able to connect to the external network. I believe it mangles the packets going out. There may be a way to get this to work, but I've never done it.

One option is to disable the DHCP server and router part of the modem. Then let the 3 routers connect to it and request external IP addresses from your ISP. Each of the 3 routers will be accessible from the internet and will access it directly. They each do NAT and have DHCP servers and so whatever connects to them will be able to connect to the internet through them.

Another option is to only use one router, or just the modem because it sounds like it has a router built in. Then have 3 switches for the 3 areas you want to serve. You could also set up the 3 routers to just act as wireless access points and disable the DHCP servers on them so the modem would be the only DHCP server.

Comment: when I disable the dhcp at the modem, I can not connect to the modem, would you explain to me how or what to do

Comment: You may need to statically assign your computer's ip address while you're doing that. Check these sites to see if they help you to understand what you need to do overall:

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-One-Router-to-Another-to-Expand-a-Network
https://portforward.com/help/doublerouterportforwarding.htm